# Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator` in LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, list, backgroundworker

I have BackgroundWorkerCollection which is a list of a specific class. When i try to loop into the list and filter and select a single i'm getting the mentioned error.

//Code

```
Dim bw = From BackgroundWorkerLinq In BackgroundWorkerCollection Where BackgroundWorkerLinq.Id = sItemNo Select BackgroundWorkerLinq.Backgroundworker
```

Is it possible to convert the `bw` to `Backgroundworker`, the class created in the application has two properties Id(`int`) and Backgroundworker(`Backgroundworker`). So i have to convert back to the same to check if that is busy or not.

Where i'm wrong and how to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bw` will be a *sequence* of `BackgroundWorker` items - so you can't cast from that sequence to a single item. There are a number of methods which will give you a single item, e.g.

- `First`
- `FirstOrDefault`
- `Single`
- `SingleOrDefault`
- `Last`
- `LastOrDefault`

You should work out whether you should use one of those, or actually iterate over *all* the results of the query.

Comment: I'm providing where condition and the result will be a single value in which i select a property. Wont it work?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: No, the result of `Where` is *always* a sequence. That's my point. `Where` transforms a sequence into another sequence, even if that only has one element.